# TypeScript ES6 and VS-2015: calling Promise.all(promise[]) returns array of promises

Tags: typescript, es6-promise

I need to wait for an array of Promises to get resolved, and then loop the resulting values.
Looking at ES6 examples, I tried doing it as explained in `Promise.all()` (like [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)).

However, in my Visual Studio 2015 with TypeScript 2 targeting ES6, when I "await" on an array of Promises, what I get back (intellisense wise) is still an array of Promises. Why ?

Example:

```
let somePromises = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(n => Promise.resolve(n));
let resolvedPromises = await Promise.all(somePromises);
```

- `somePromises` is of type Promise<number>[] (which is fine of course).
- `resolvedPromises` is still of type Promise<number>[]. Why not number[] ?

EDIT:

See image

[image]

Comment: This works as expected in Visual Studio Code, I would be very surprised if it's any different in VS15. Is it really that resolvedPromises is an array of Promises instead of numbers or the return value of the async function is array of Promises? Because that is what it should be

Comment: @DavidBohunek, see screenshot of intellisense.

Comment: `await` only works inside `async` functions. Is this inside one?

Comment: @jib, yes, of course (: